# '/etc/init.d' or 'service' equivalent on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, osx-lion

Is there any `/etc/init.d` or `service` equivalent on Mac OS X Lion?
I want to start/stop daemons, such as apache.

Comment: The OS X equivalent is [`launchd`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launchd)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
man launchd
```

> DESCRIPTION
>        launchd manages processes, both for the system as a whole and for individual users.  The pri-
>        mary and preferred interface to launchd is via the launchctl(1) tool which (among other
>        options) allows the user or administrator to load and unload jobs.  Where possible, it is
>        preferable for jobs to launch on demand based on criteria specified in their respective con-
>        figuration files.
>
> During boot launchd is invoked by the kernel to run as the first process on the system and to
>        further bootstrap the rest of the system.
>
> You cannot invoke launchd directly.